# Authentication cookie disappears in react SPA after some time

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have an SPA, written in React together with ASP.net core for hosting.

To authenticate the app, we are using IdentityServer4 and use a cookie. The client is configured according to the sample, described here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/4_JavaScriptClient/src

For authenticating a user, everythings works fine. It will be redirected to the login page. After signing in, redirection to the SPA is done. The authentiation cookie is set as expected with:

- HttpOnly = true
- Secure = true
- SameSite = None
- Expires / Max-age = one week from login time

The cookie is used also in other MVC (.net core and MVC 5) applications for authentication reasons.
In the SPA, we are also using SignalR, which needs the cookie for authentication.

**Our issue:**

After about 30 minutes of idle time in the browser and either doing a refresh or navigating, the authentication cookie (and only that, other remains) is disappearing from the browser automatically. Then the user has to sign in again. Why does this happen together with the SPA?

**Code**

Complete code can be found in [github](https://github.com/wedge76/AuthenticationIssues)

*Client*

Snippets of `UserService.ts`

```
const openIdConnectConfig: UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: baseUrls.person,
  client_id: "js",
  redirect_uri: joinUrl(baseUrls.spa, "signincallback"),
  response_type: "code",
  scope: "openid offline_access profile Person.Api Translation.Api",
  post_logout_redirect_uri: baseUrls.spa,
  automaticSilentRenew: true
};

export const getUserService = asFactory(() => {
  const userManager = new UserManager(openIdConnectConfig);
  return createInstance(createStateHandler(defaultUserState), userManager, createSignInProcess(userManager));
}, sameInstancePerSameArguments());
```

*Server*

Snipped of `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Log.Information($"Start configuring services. Environment: {_environment.EnvironmentName}");
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddIdentity<LoginInputModel, RoleDto>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var certificate = LoadSigningCertificate();
    var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                                                           {
                                                               options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                                                               options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                                                               options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                                                               options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                                                           })
                                        .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
                                        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
                                        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                                        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                                        .AddInMemoryClients(new ClientConfigLoader().LoadClients(Configuration));

    if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        identityServerBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                                            {
                                                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                                                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                                            });

    services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(_sharedAuthTicketKeys))
            .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

    services.AddAsposeMailLicense(Configuration);
    var optionalStartupSettings = SetupStartupSettings();
    if (optionalStartupSettings.IsSome)
    {
        var settings = optionalStartupSettings.Value;

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                                            {
                                                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
                                                options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Auth.Cookie";
                                                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                                                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                                                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                                                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
                                                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                                            });

        var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Identity.Application"; });
        authBuilder = ConfigureSaml2(authBuilder, settings);
        authBuilder = ConfigureGoogle(authBuilder);
        authBuilder.AddCookie();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Startup settings are not configured in appsettings.json.");
    }

    SetupEntityFramework(services);
}
```

Snippet of identity server client config from `appsettings.json`

```
{
    "Enabled": true,
    "ClientId": "js",
    "ClientName": "JavaScript Client",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "authorization_code" ],
    "RequirePkce": true,
    "RequireClientSecret": false,
    "RedirectUris": [ "https://dev.myCompany.ch/i/signincallback", "https://dev.myCompany.com/i/signincallback", "https://dev.myCompany.de/i/signincallback" ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "https://dev.myCompany.ch/i/", "https://dev.myCompany.com/i/", "https://dev.myCompany.de/i/" ],
    "AllowedCorsOrigins": [],
    "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "offline_access", "profile", "Translation.Api", "Person.Api" ],
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true
}
```

**Update**

In the meantime I discovered that the cookie, while requesting `https://ourdomain/.well-known/openid-configuration` after 30 minutes idle time, has lost the values of *Domain, Path, Expires/Max-Age, HttpOnly, Secure and SameSite.None*. Those values have definitely been set after signing in.
The response cookie has the value of *Expires/Max-Age* set to a time in the past and therefore the cookie will be dropped by the browser.
[image: Network traffic]

Has anyone an idea, why those values got lost after some time?

Comment: Are you ticking "Remember me" to create a persistent login? Do you have any automatic renewal of the SPA auth token? Whats the lifetime for the client token?

Comment: - Remember me: yes is set.
- Automatical renewal: yes, we are using oidc-client(https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client) with automaticSilentRenew
- Client token lifetime: According to https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html (defaults to 3600 seconds / 1 hour)

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong and you haven't posted code related to authentication, DataProtectionKeys are not relevant. Can you post some code from client/server? Also seems you are confused about the auth flow as you say "After 30 minutes, the cookie is disappearing automatically. the user has to sign in again" The SPA should use a token for auth (not cookie) which lasts 1 hour then it silent renews where the cookie is checked by IdSrv. You focus on the cookie but it shouldnt be an issue until 1 hour passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to tackle this.

It had to do with the configuration of IdentityServer. The missing part was the method `AddAspNetIdentity<LoginInputModel>()`.

*Before:*

```
var certificate = LoadSigningCertificate();
var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                                                       {
                                                           options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                                                           options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                                                           options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                                                           options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                                                       })
                                    .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
                                    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
                                    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                                    .AddInMemoryClients(new ClientConfigLoader().LoadClients(Configuration));
```

*Now:*

```
var certificate = LoadSigningCertificate();
var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                                                       {
                                                           options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                                                           options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                                                           options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                                                           options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                                                       })
                                    .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
                                    .AddAspNetIdentity<LoginInputModel>()
                                    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
                                    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                                    .AddInMemoryClients(new ClientConfigLoader().LoadClients(Configuration));
```

With that additional configuration line, Identity Server is handling the cookie correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in Configure method in Startup.cs :

```
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
            MinimumSameSitePolicy=SameSiteMode.None
        });
```

add this before using identity server service:

```
       app.UseIdentityServer();
```

You need to check "HttpOnly" option for your situation because it can give trouble with oidc client on react.